# Android button doesn't react

Tags: android, button, interface, multi-touch

I'm facing a tough problem right now regarding the simplest thing: a Button.

I have a big application where i need multitouch capabilities embedded in a custom joypad-like interface. For this interface i have a custom joystick and buttons. The problem is this buttons receive the touch event but don't give the usual visual feedback (changing color while touched). These buttons are simple extensions of the base Button class.

Any ideas on why this happens?
I'm doing the event separation myself for multitouch but this isn't the issue as the Buttons receive the event as expected.

If code needed, comment please.

Thanks in advance,
JQCorreia

Comment: It is somewhat a mess... Cleansing Refactoring scheduled altough :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and use custom [`StateListDrawables`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for your buttons.

Comment: Why is that? I suppose i can use the StateList of the base Button? Thks for the swift reply!